# How to structure a recursive async/await function for firestore in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

**What I am trying to do:**
I am trying to retrieve all comments and their replies from firestore (firebase database) using a recursive method. Here is the structure of the data:
[image]

**What is the problem**
The parent asynchronous function does not wait for the nested asynchronous function to complete.

```
getThread = async (req, res) => {
    // Getting comments belonging to thread
    const thread_document = await db.doc(`/Threads/${req.params.threadid}`).get()
    threadData = thread_document.data()
    threadData.threadid = thread_document.id
    const comment_query = await db.collection('Comments').where('threadid', '==', threadData.threadid).get()

    // Getting replies belonging to comments
    for (document of comment_query){
    let commentData = await getReplies(document.id)
    threadData.comments.push(commentData )
    }
  return res.json(threadData)
}

//Recursive function to retrieve replies
getReplies = async (id) => {
    let comment = await db.doc(`/Comments/${id}`).get()
    let commentData = comment.data()
  
    commentData.comment_replies = commentData.replies.map(idx => {
      // The parent async function does not wait for the the async function here to finish.
      // Placing a await keyword here will raise the error 'await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules' 
      return getReplies(idx)
    })
    console.log(commentData)
    return commentData
}
```

Given the following example,
[image]
Since the parent async function does not wait for the nested async function, the order of execution  now is A -> B -> a, and a fails to be mapped into `commentData` and commentData for comment A would end up empty. Hence, I want to program to do A -> a -> B. To do so, I would like to place a await keyword just before the getReplies like

```
return await getReplies(idx)
```

but it will raise the error,

```
await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules.
```

Which is confusing as `getReplies` is already a async function. I've looked into other solutions in stackoverflow but I am not able to get the recursive function working. Any insights would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
commentData.comment_replies = commentData.replies.map(idx => {
  // ...
  return getReplies(idx)
})
```

This map statement is going to create an array of promises, but not wait for those promises to finish. You should use Promise.all to combine them into a single promise, and then await that promise to get the array of comment replies:

```
const promises = commentData.replies.map(idx => {
  return getReplies(idx);
});
commentData.comment_replies = await Promise.all(promises);
```

> Which is confusing as getReplies is already a async function.

You were getting that error because the function you're inside is `idx => { return getReplies(idx) }`, which is not an async function. But putting an await in there is not a solution to your problem anyway.